# Pass bool param to a powershell script in Jenkinsfile multiline parameterised pipeline

Tags: powershell, jenkins-pipeline

In my Jenkinsfile I have something like:

```
def addDollar(param) {
  return "\$" + param
}
parameters {
    booleanParam(
        defaultValue: false,
        name: 'FORCE_UPGRADE'
    )
}
environment {
    FORCE_UPGRADE = addDollar(params.FORCE_UPGRADE)
}
stages {
    stage('Test') {
        steps {
            powershell script: ".\\test.ps1 -forceUpgrade ${env:FORCE_UPGRADE}"
        }
    }
 stage('Test Multiline') {
        steps {
            powershell script: '''
                 .\\test.ps1 `
                     -forceUpgrade $env:FORCE_UPGRADE
            '''
        }
    }
}
```

and the powershell script is

```
param (
   [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][boolean]$forceUpgrade=$false
)

if($forceUpgrade) {
 Write-Host "Forcing upgrade"
}
```

This jenkins stage `Test` works as expected but `Test Multiline` erorrs with `ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException`:

`Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'forceUpgrade'. Cannot convert value "System.String" to type "System.Boolean". Boolean parameters accept only Boolean values and
numbers, such as $True, $False, 1 or 0.`

I get the same error if I run

- `.\test.ps1 -forceUpgrade false` rather than
- `.\test.ps1 -forceUpgrade $false`

Any ideas how to get the Jenkins `Test Multiline` stage working? I have a script where i need to pass a number of args, would be ideal to prevent horizontal scrolling using multiline powershell

Comment: if those are env variables, why dont you pull them inside the script?

Comment: Passing params into the script allows me to validate mandatory ones, rather than explicitly checking if all required env variables have been set

Comment: But you give the value `$forceUpgrade` a default value of `$false`, so Mandatory should be $false too. Next, remember that environment values are STRINGS. I would advice calling the powershell function with boolean values instead of a string value taken from the environment, OR let the PowerShell script handle the reading of the environment variable.

Comment: In any case, drop the `addDollar` stuff because you don't need it. Then set the environment value to either the strings `true` or `false` or even `0` or `1`
Within PowerShell you can then convert this STRING to a boolean value. Something like `[bool]$bool = $false; if ([Boolean]::TryParse($forceUpgrade, [ref]$bool)) { $forceUpgrade = $bool } else { $forceUpgrade = $false }`. In the PowerShell script change the parameter to `[Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]$forceUpgrade= 'false'`

Answer (score 0):

Change the powershell input to a `[string]` instead of a `[boolean]`

```
[string]$forceUpgrade = $false
```

you will still be able to use the `$forceUpgrade` variable as a bool in the conditional in the powershell also.